# expresion regular para comprobar nombre en c#

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de comprobar un nombre (jorge) con una expresión regular de la siguiente manera:

```
Regex name_validation = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$");

if(name_validation.IsMatch(obj.firstName.Value){
 MessageBox.Show("Error. El nombre solo debe contener letras");   
}
```

el `obj.firstName.Value` es `jorge`. Cuando lo ejecuto, entra en el `if` y me muestra el mensaje de error.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente debes negar la condición:

```
if(!name_validation.IsMatch(obj.firstName.Value)){
    MessageBox.Show("Error. El nombre solo debe contener letras");   
}
```

`^[a-zA-Z]+$` hace `match` si todos los caracteres son letras. Lo que tu quieres es que de el mensaje de error si no lo son, así que debes negar el `IsMatch`.

Comment: funciona!!! Muchas gracias!!